# Cannot set href attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have this link elemnet in my form

```
    <li><a id="pic">Upload Picture</a></li>
```

I want to set its href attribute dynamically So i call a javascript like this

```
    <script>fetch_me()</script>
```

And here is the javascript function

```
    function fetch_me()
    {
        //alert("hi");
        var path = location.pathname;
        var uri = path.split("?");
        var param = uri[1].split("&");
        var day = param[0].split("=")[1];
        var month = param[1].split("=")[1];
        var year = param[2].split("=")[1];
        var date = "day="+day+"&month="+month+"&year="+year;
        var url2 = "/upload_pic.html/"+encodeURIComponent(date);
        var pic_link = document.getElementById("pic");
        //pic_link.prop("href",url2);
        //pic_link.href(url2);
        //pic_link.setAttribute("href",url2);
        pic_link.attr("href",url2);

    }
```

I have tried setAttribute, prop , attr, .href but nothing is working.

P.S : The function getting called as i tested it with the alert statement in the first line.

Comment: try `pic_link.href=url2;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.attr` is jQuery.

```
pic_link.setAttribute("href",url2);
```

Or even shorter:

```
pic_link.href = url2;
```

Comment: Oh brilliant catch. The problem was with  `path = location.pathname;`. changed it to `path = document.URL;` and it worked. Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#pic").prop( "href", url2 );
```

and do not forget to include jquery. Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/chetangawai/yL3nX/